# SSRS Dataset Rendering

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have created a stored procedure where its columns can change names and the number of columns fluctuate as well.  Is there a way to auto generate the report in SSRS depending on the result set.  My main concern is to output from 3 columns to lets say 10 columns.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the visibility of columns using the Column Visibility in conjunction with some parameter you define for control flow. It is a bit more difficult to do column wise shifting then row shifting, as with groups. Another thought would be to look into column grouping. In SSRS you can simulate the PIVOT command using column groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the matrix, which will show the number of columns as they are generated. 
Include (Drag from DATASETS)  your data in DATA and the field (dynamic column) in columns.
Hope this helps you.